# Assigning anonymous function that returns anonymous function

Tags: javascript

What is the difference in JavaScript between calling something like this:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
    return function (e) {
        loadData(e.target.result); 
    };
})(file);

reader.readAsText(file);
```

and (result is the same in the loadData function):

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
    loadData(e.target.result);
}; 

reader.readAsText(file);
```

I have used JavaScript for simple tasks (input validation, simple ajax calls) until now but now I need some deeper undestanding...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific case there is no difference (note that the function in your first fragment is invoked with the parameter `file`, but since you ignore it it shouldn't have any side effects). However, have a look at the following example:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

var my_temporary_var = 42;

reader.onload = function(e){
    loadData(e.target.result, my_temporary_var);
}
```

So far everything is the same. But if you change `my_temporary_var` it will also be changed *inside* of your anonymous function. To prevent this you create a closure:

```
reader.onload = (function(some_value) {
    return function(e){
        loadData(e.target.result, some_value);
    };
})(my_temporary_var);
```

You create an anonymous function which takes the argument you want to bind to another function and then call this function immediately. Note that the dependency on `my_temporary_var` has been resolved.

#### Other example

Some people like to create many functions in a for-loop:

```
var i;
for(i = 0; i < myObjects.length; ++i)
    myObjects[i].onload = function(e) { myObjects[i].doSomething(); };
```

Lets assume that `myObjects[0].onload` will be handled first, but *after* the for loop. The given handler `function(e) { myObjects[i].doSomething(); };` uses the object `myObjects[i]`. However, `i == myObjects.length`: we access an object which isn't even there! And since we try to access an attribute of that function, we'll get an exception and the script will stop.

This happened because `i` in the anonymous function is a reference, and not used as a value. In order to prevent this you must use a closure:

```
var i;
for(i = 0; i < myObjects.length; ++i)
    myObjects[i].onload = (function(index){
        return function(e) { myObjects[index].doSomething(); };
    })(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's much like the same as the following examples:

```
var fruit = "Apple";

var fruit = (function(X) {
    return "Apple";
})(1);
```

You just enclose the assignment in a closure, which in the above case serves no purpose at all. But if you do something like this:

```
var fruit_names = ["Pear", "Apple"];
var fruits = [];
for (x in fruits) {
    fruits.push({
        getName: (function(fruit_id) {
            return fruits[fruit_id];
        })(x)
    });
}
```

You just created an array of objects which all have the `getName` function, which return their own names from the `fruit_names` array. This kind of use of closures can create really flexible structures, since in this example you can change the name of the fruit objects, by changing the `fruit_names` array, which serves as a configuration interface for your objects.